# Any good way to convert html table (with colored text, images, etc) to Word, pdf, or Excel

Tags: html, pdf, html-table, export

I have a html table.  Inside the table are images, links (different font colors, etc).  What is the easiest way to get this exported into an ms office format (powerpoint, excel, word, pdf)?  I was going to start hand writing this but figured I would throw out this question if there was any thing that would help with this conversion  . . .  my really low budget solution is to take a screen shot and resize to fit on a page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a PDF printer and open the html in a browser, then choose print, as if to a normal printer, and the output is converted into a pdf.

For windows you can download and install from this page:

http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp

This software:

1. http://www.cutepdf.com/download/converter.exe
2. http://www.cutepdf.com/download/CuteWriter.exe

For other operating systems it is probably a built in feature when you try to print.

Comment: On a side note, I prefer using Adobe PDF

Comment: I don't think Adobe PDF creator is free... but it is definitely more advanced and might produce smaller, better PDFs. For a serious PDF it is probably best, bit for quick and easy, I would use CutePDF writer - which is actually pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always work perfectly, but most of the time I can open any html files I have in adobe, and it will auto convert them to pdf and you can save, usually everything looks the way it should. You can also just open the html in word, but it doesn't work so well if you are using any css.

Answer (score 0):

This page has information on transforming XML to Word XML format: http://www.linkwerk.com/pub/xml/invitation/xml2wordml/

I haven't used it, but perhaps it will be helpful.